# Image not showing on real device using linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

My layout is divided into 3 which is an imageview and another 2 linearlayout. The imageview has a weight of 2 and 1 for each linearlayout and that sums to 4. In android studio, the layouts works well but when I tried to test in on a real device, here is what I got:

[image]

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:weightSum="4"
    tools:context="com.newvillemovement.smartmyjob.RegisterActivity_page1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Korean"
            android:id="@id/btnKorean"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="btnKorean"
            android:src="@drawable/btnkoreanomal" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Foreigner"
            android:id="@id/btnForeigner"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:onClick="btnForeigner"
            android:src="@drawable/btnforeignernormal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Events"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:src="@drawable/img_event_title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/txt_event"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/footertext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="About About About About About About About About About About About About About"
            android:src="@drawable/footer"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout_height for ImageView and LinearLayouts **must** be **0dp**! So that it fixes with weight, try now.

Comment: it works, thanks! what's the reason for this? should all the children's height of linearlayout be 0dp for the weight to work? ill accept this answer in 9 mins, just waiting for the time..

Comment: No, **only the LinearLayouts**. See, **they are DIRECT children of the LinearLayout with weightSum = 4**. Android automatically fixes that for you. If the parent's orientation was **horizontal**, you might have set **layout_width = "0dp"**. By the way, **weightSum is OPTIONAL**

Answer (score 2):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_margin="20dp"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/abc" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="btnKorean"
        android:text="Korean" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="btnForeigner"
        android:text="Foreigner" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Events" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/footertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="About About About About About About About About About About  About" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing weight you can use wrap content for height and width for all controls.That will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need draw different layout in different size device
Create layout folder in res

1. layout-xlarge
2. layout-large
3. layout-normal
4. layout-small

and create same xml in different size layout folder so that you can custom layout in 
different size device